MSSQL: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
I am tyring to connect with SQL Server from my kubernetes cluster.
Cluster is hosted on office network.
Working for internal network db server connection and not able to connect to db server on aws
Scenario 1:
Connecting with the database server hosted in the office itself, working fine.
Scenario 2:
Connecting with the db server hosted on AWS, Throwing above error.
How am I connecting?
Using IP address of the db server.
I tried using <ip.port> as well same error.
Am not getting this error from my API gateway which is in js. So it has to be pyodbc issue.
This is the db string
DEFAULT_DRIVER = "SQL Server"
DEFAULT_DRIVER_ODBC = "ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server"
DEFAULT_DIALECT = "mssql+pyodbc"


# allows Solenoid to work on macs/unix systems
DEFAULT_DRIVER_UNIX = "/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql18/lib64/libmsodbcsql-18.4.so.1.0"
DEFAULT_DRIVER_ODBC_UNIX = "/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib"

if platform.system() == "Linux":
    DEFAULT_DRIVER = DEFAULT_DRIVER_UNIX
    DEFAULT_DRIVER_ODBC = DEFAULT_DRIVER_UNIX


def create_db_string(*, server, database, username, password, driver=DEFAULT_DRIVER):
    return (
        f"Driver={driver};"
        f"Server={server};"
        f"Database={database};"
        f"uid={username};"
        f"pwd={password};"
        "Trusted_Connection=no;"
        "integratedSecurity=false;"
        "TrustServerCertificate=yes;"
    )

I tried using DEFAULT_DRIVER_ODBC as well for the driver, did not work.
This is my docker image
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /app

ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/app"

ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y

# Install required packages
RUN apt install -y \
    python3 python3-pip \
    unixodbc-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    wget \
    curl \
    gnupg2 \
    dpkg-dev \
    gcc \
    gnupg \
    libbluetooth-dev \
    libbz2-dev \
    libc6-dev \
    libdb-dev \
    libexpat1-dev \
    libffi-dev \
    libgdbm-dev \
    liblzma-dev \
    libncursesw5-dev \
    libreadline-dev \
    libsqlite3-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    make \
    tk-dev \
    uuid-dev \
    wget \
    xz-utils \
    zlib1g-dev \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    build-essential \
    gcc \
    g++ 

# Install unixODBC 2.3.12
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl
RUN curl -L --insecure https://www.unixodbc.org/unixODBC-2.3.12.tar.gz -o unixODBC-2.3.12.tar.gz
RUN tar zxvf unixODBC-2.3.12.tar.gz
RUN cd unixODBC-2.3.12 && ./configure && make && make install
RUN rm -rf unixODBC-2.3.12 unixODBC-2.3.12.tar.gz

# Add the Microsoft repository and install the ODBC driver 18 for SQL Server
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - && \
    curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18 && \
    ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools18 && \
    echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> /root/.bashrc && \
    . /root/.bashrc

# # Create a symbolic link for the Microsoft SQL Server client library
RUN ln -s /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql18/lib64/libmsodbcsql-18.4.so.1.1 /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql18/lib64/libmsodbcsql-18.4.so.1.0

# Modify the existing odbcinst.ini file
RUN echo '[ODBC]\n\
    Trace = No\n\
    Trace File = /tmp/sql.log\n\
    Pooling = Yes\n\
    \n\
    [ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]\n\
    Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server\n\
    Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql18/lib64/libmsodbcsql-18.4.so.1.1\n\
    UsageCount=1\n\
    CPTimeout=600' >> /etc/odbcinst.ini

# Copy only the requirements file first to leverage Docker cache
COPY app/prod_requirements.txt app/prod_requirements.txt

RUN pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall -r app/prod_requirements.txt
RUN pip install pandas numpy scipy gunicorn gevent SQLAlchemy==2.0.32

# Copy the application code
COPY app app

# Expose port 4000
EXPOSE 4000

# Run the application with gunicorn
CMD ["gunicorn", "-w", "2", "-k", "gevent", "-b", "0.0.0.0:4000", "app.app:app"]

Reduced The version to 17, still the issue persists
Github Issue

Aside... if you docker run -it --rm python:3.9 cat /etc/os-release you'll see that it's based on Debian 12 Bookworm, so you shouldn't be trying to install packages from Microsoft's Ubuntu 20.04 repository.

Aside... apt-key-add has been deprecated since Debian 9 days. Consider treating Docker build warnings as errrors.

@AlwaysLearning Thanks for the suggestions, I updated the mssql import to debian, still the issue persists.
And it is the same issue, It is working when connecting with the db server inside the office network but it is throwing above error when connecting with db server on aws
